# Same data with different filter in a single visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have a table like:
item startdate enddate.

I want to create a single visual in Power BI with how many item start each quarter and how many item end each quarter.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the ways to do it.

Let's say your table is called `items1`

- create a copy of `items1` - `items2`
- at this point you can remove columns `items1[enddate]` and `items2[startdate]`
- if your dates include time part, remove it
- create a date table, `dates`, make sure it's populated.
- create relationships between `dates` and `items1[startdate]`, `dates` and `items2[enddate]`
- plot `countrows(items1)` and `countrows(items2)` against `dates`